# abas-erp DATEV export interface description

Tags: erp, abas

Hello abas community :)

I was wondering if there is an description in PDF format, explaining the datev export interface which is incorporated in the abas-erp standard. I have seen the configuration tutorial in the abas online help, but seriously, there must be a PDF descritpion of the export schema.

It would be really great if someone could help me find one.

Comment: Unfortunately I know no free official documentation of the DATEV export interface. You can by the specs from http://www.datev.de/portal/ShowPage.do?pid=dpi&nid=115908&stat_Mparam=int_url_datev_datevformat

Comment: found a similar question on stackoverflow. Unfortunately also without an answer but with an external link to a kind of documentation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31357286/datev-dtvf-format

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow, Slaushy =)

I think the export schema might be protected stuff, like Alexander suggested in his comment.
For a  reliable answer you should contact datev and most likely have to pay for the information.
Probably the abas AG have more experience and maybe they share a document with the actual export schema  on request.

If you contact the abas AG may you post their answer here (so other users know if they have to contact abas or datev if they have the same problem)? (=